# AJAX request to Keycloak not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, keycloak

I have a request to keycloak server to obtain authentication token. The request works in Chrome/FF/Opera, but not in Internet Explorer.

This is the request:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://url/to/server",
    headers: {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: false,
    data: 'username=test&password=test&.....', // all parameters
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.access_token);
    error: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

In IE, it returns {"error": "unknown_error"} and status 500. This is from the keycloak server log:

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-522) 
Uncaught server error: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.BaseHttpRequest.getFormParameters(BaseHttpRequest.java:61)
```

I tried with different headers and parameters but could not make it work.
Would appreciate if anyone has any suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: IE is about to end support, I recommend that you could focus more on modern browsers. You can also try testing in Edge IE mode to check if the same issue occurs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have clients that use it. Anyway, I tried testing in Edge IE mode and I have the same problem, while in Edge it works fine.